# Using xlib to out put 8000 pictures

Tags: c++, image, xlib

The whole goal of the program is to output 8000 pictures to the screen. This is how far i have gotten in that regard.

if you could just help me out put pictures instead of empty space I should be good since I am not very well versed in xlib.

i want to then change the pictures that are on screen later.

`#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

void draw(char *rgb_out, int w, int h)
{
for(int i=0; i<w*h*4; i++)
*rgb_out++ = rand();
}

XImage *create_ximage(Display *display, Visual *visual, int width, int height)
{
char *image32 = (char *)malloc(width * height * 4);
draw(image32, width, height);
return XCreateImage(display, visual, 24, ZPixmap, 0, image32, width, height, 32, 0);
}

int x11_err_handler(Display *pd, XErrorEvent *pxev)
{
char msg[4096] = { 0 };
XGetErrorText(pd, pxev -> error_code, msg, sizeof(msg));
printf("%s\n", msg);
return 0;
}

draw_graphics(Window win, GC gc, int window_width, int window_height)

{
int x, y;
unsigned int width, height;
height = window_height/2;
width = 3 * window_width/4;
x = window_width/2 - width/2;  /* Center */
y = window_height/2 - height/2;
XDrawRectangle(display, win, gc, x, y, width, height);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
Display                 *display;
    Visual                  *visual;
    int                     depth;
    XSetWindowAttributes    frame_attributes;
    Window                  frame_window;
    XFontStruct             *fontinfo;
    XGCValues               gr_values;
    GC                      graphical_context;
    XKeyEvent               event;
    char                    hello_string[] = "Hello World";
    int                     hello_string_length = strlen(hello_string);
    int                     i = 0;
    int                     t = 0;
    int                     x = 15;
    int                     y = 15;


    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    visual = DefaultVisual(display, 0);
    depth  = DefaultDepth(display, 0);

    frame_attributes.background_pixel = XWhitePixel(display, 0);
    /* create the application window */
    frame_window = XCreateWindow(display, XRootWindow(display, 0),
                                 0, 0, 1200, 1200, 5, depth,
                                 InputOutput, visual, CWBackPixel,
                                 &frame_attributes);
    XStoreName(display, frame_window, "Hello World Example");
    XSelectInput(display, frame_window, ExposureMask | StructureNotifyMask);

    fontinfo = XLoadQueryFont(display, "10x20");
    gr_values.font = fontinfo->fid;
    gr_values.foreground = XBlackPixel(display, 0);
    gr_values.background = XWhitePixel(display, 0);
    graphical_context = XCreateGC(display, frame_window,
                                  GCFont+GCForeground+GCBackground, &gr_values);
    XMapWindow(display, frame_window);

    while ( 1 ) {
        XNextEvent(display, (XEvent *)&event);
        switch ( event.type ) {
            case Expose:
            {
         while (i < 64){
           i = 0;
                while(i < 125)
        {

                XImage *ximage = create_ximage(display, visual, 125, 125);
                XPutImage(display, frame_window, graphical_context, ximage, 0, 0, x, y, 9, 9);

        XDestroyImage(ximage);

                XFlush(display);
                ++i;
        x = x + 9;                
        }
        y = y + 9;
    x = 9;

    ++t;
    i = t;
        }                   
        usleep(2);
            }
          default:
              break;
       }
    }    
 return(0);

}`

Comment: Which program? Which 8,000 images? What is the context? What's changing dynamically?

Comment: I need to output a picture. this program outputs empty picture spaces in a popup window. everywhere that I have found information there is no code that will help me understand how to make that work. If you compile the code you will see how there are empty pixel spaces where the 8000 pictures should be. 

If you could help me put the pictures in the spaces then all will be good.

Comment: You fill the images with random values. What do you expect?